# Powershell: Calling a script from foreach in another script doesn't get the desired effect

Tags: powershell

In this script below. When I enter the whole script into the powershell command line then call it with a server name, it works fine. But when i call it from this script:

```
`sl C:\PowershellScripts
 . ./psscript_Get-FreeSpaceFrag.ps1
 $svl = gc 'C:\PowershellScripts\ebi_serverlist.txt'
 $x = {foreach ($s in $svl) {write-host "Getting Disk Info for Server $s" -   
 foregroundcolor "Green"; Get-FreeSpaceFrag $s; start-sleep -s 5; }}
 $x.invoke() | export-csv "C:\PowershellScripts\DiskInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation`
```

It will not work, meaning that the csv file is empty after it processes for a while.

```
Function Get-FreeSpaceFrag ($s)
{ 
       trap {write-host "Can't connect to WMI on server $s"  -ForeGroundColor "Red" 
         continue 
} 
 $dt = get-date 
 $Scope = new-object System.Management.ManagementScope "\\$s\root\cimv2" 
 $query = new-object System.Management.ObjectQuery "SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume" 
 $searcher = new-object System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher $scope,$query 
 $SearchOption = $searcher.get_options() 
 $timeout = new-timespan -seconds 10 
 $SearchOption.set_timeout($timeout) 
 $SearchOption 
 $searcher.set_options($SearchOption) 
 $volumes = $searcher.get() 

        $fr = {foreach ($v in $volumes | where {$_.capacity -gt 0}){ 
        $frag=($v.defraganalysis().defraganalysis).totalPercentFragmentation 
        $v | Add-Member -Name Frag -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $frag -Force -        
        PassThru 
        } } 
       $fr.invoke() | select @{N="Server";E={$_.Systemname}}, DriveLetter, Label,                
       Capacity, FreeSpace, @{N="PercentFree";E={"{0,9:N0}" -f  
       (($_.FreeSpace/1gb)/($_.Capacity/1gb)*100)}}, Frag, @{N="InfoDate";E={$dt}}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this a bit harder than it should be i.e. I'm not sure why you need part of the code in an anoymous scriptblock?  Try this instead:

```
 . ./psscript_Get-FreeSpaceFrag.ps1
Get-Content 'C:\PowershellScripts\ebi_serverlist.txt' | 
    Foreach {Write-Host "Getting Disk Info for Server $_" -foregroundcolor "Green" `
             Get-FreeSpaceFrag $_} |
    Export-Csv "C:\PowershellScripts\DiskInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Not sure if it will solve the problem but you can also simplify this part of your function:

```
$volumes | Where {$_.capacity -gt 0} | Foreach { $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty Frag `
         ($_.defraganalysis().defraganalysis.totalPercentFragmentation) -PassThru} |
  Select @{N="Server";E={$_.Systemname}}, DriveLetter,Label,Capacity,FreeSpace, 
         @{N="PercFree";E={"{0,9:N0}" -f (($_.FreeSpace/1gb)/($_.Capacity/1gb)*100)}},
         Frag, @{N="InfoDate";E={$dt}
```

BTW rather than invoking a scriptblock like this `$fr.invoke()` the canonical way in PowerShell is to use the call operator like so `&$fr`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That still gives me the same result as before. If there were a rights issue, this would throw an exception, correct? I wonder if it's the time-out setting, I'll try upping it. But that wouldn't explain why it works as expected when the code is run inline.

Comment: Well I upped the time-out and still same result.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this error after that last change: `You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At C:\PowershellScripts\psscript_Get-FreeSpaceFrag.ps1:19 char:76
+          (($_.defraganalysis().defraganalysis).totalPercentFragmentation) -P <<<< assThru} |`

Comment: Whenever you paste PowerShell script from SO you have to watch out for any whitespace after line continuations chars (back tick).  Remove the extra space after the back tick on the first line where the script is doing an Add-Member.

Comment: Yup I noticed that the very first time and fixed it. But it didn;t change the result anyway.

Comment: I believe the error indicates there are unbalanced parens around the $_.defraganalysis .... expression.  `-PassThru` should be interpreted as a parameter to Add-Member and not part of the preceeding expression.

Comment: Thanks! It runs now, however, when I try to export-csv "filename.csv" it creates an empty csv file, if I use export-clixml, or out-string, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your problem in the process block?

```
 $x = {foreach ($s in $svl) {start-sleep -s 5; 
  write-host "Getting Disk Info for Server $s" -foregroundcolor "Green"; 
  Get-FreeSpaceFrag $s;}}
```